# Difficulty finding a Python 3.x implementation of the familiar C for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm inexperienced in Python and started with Python 3.4.

I read over the Python 3.x documentation on [loop idioms](http://docs.python.org/release/3.4.0/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-loopidioms), and haven't found a way of constructing a familiar C-family *for-loop*, i.e.

```
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       A[i] = value;
   }
```

Writing a *for*-loop like this in Python seems all but impossible by design. Does anyone know the reason why Python iteration over a sequence follows a pattern like

```
for x in iterable: # e.g. range, itertools.count, generator functions
    pass;
```

Is this more efficient, convenient, or reduces index-out-of-bounds exception?

Comment: Uh, the reason? Guido thinks `for i in range(n):` is fine. See [PEP284](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0284/).

Comment: @JGreenwell: That's hardly a useful tag!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the question is about "why one type of for loop is preferred over another" - tags should reflect what the question is about (here it is about for-loops and does not just contain them) and be useful for future searching: adding this tag fulfills both. Actually I would think that the rejection reason "to small an edit" would be more acceptable (considered it as too small but cite my above reasons for why)

Comment: The C syntax was settled on relatively early and decisions reflected common practical situations at that time. Languages that have come later have the benefit of hindsight. Avoiding off-by-one-errors is a big incentive to try different approaches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for lower <= var < upper:
```

That was [the proposed syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0284/) for a C-style loop. I say "was the proposed syntax", because PEP 284 was rejected, because:

> Specifically, Guido did not buy the premise that the range() format needed fixing, "The whole point (15 years ago) of range() was to *avoid* needing syntax to specify a loop over numbers. I think it's worked out well and there's nothing that needs to be fixed (except range() needs to become an iterator, which it will in Python 3.0)."

So no `for lower <= var < upper:` for us.

Now, how to get a C-style loop? Well, you can use `range([start,]end[,step])`.

```
for i in range(0,len(blah),3):
    blah[i] += merp #alters every third element of blah
                    #step defaults to 1 if left off
```

You can `enumerate` if you need both index and value:

```
for i,j in enumerate(blah):
    merp[j].append(i)
```

If you wanted to look at two (or more!) iterators together you can `zip` them (Also: [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) and [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest))

```
for i,j in zip(foo,bar):
    if i == j: print("Scooby-Doo!")
```

And finally, there's always the `while` loop

```
i = 0
while i < upper:
    A[i] = b
    i++
```

Addendum: There's also [PEP 276](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0276/), which suggested making `int`s iterable, which was also rejected. Still would have been half-open

Comment: That proposal is easy to read, but Guido's rejection looks justified (although [range](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#range) would be clearer if the *start*, *stop* parameters were inclusive bounds, as *count* appears to be a more fitting name for *stop*, at least based on the usage of `range` in examples I've seen...). In certain problems it would be easier to use range modified as: `range(L, R if L == 0 else R + 1)` assuming interval [L, R].

Comment: the answer is confusing. Why would you put unrelated non-Python syntax at the top? (there are many rejected ideas) I don't see the idiomatic Python equivalent of: `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) A[i] = value;`

Comment: `for i in range(n): A[i] = value` and the while loop would both work for that case.

Answer (score 5):

`range(n)` produces a suitable iterable :)

```
for i in range(n):
    A[i] = value
```

for the more general case (not just counting) you should transform to a while loop. eg

```
i = 0
while i < n:
    A[i] = value
    i += 1
```

Comment: I know this might be natural to some, but it's worth noting that `range(n)` returns a generator-like object with "elements" in the range [0, n) in Python 3. Python 2's `range` returns a list object.

Comment: I didn't find many examples of `while` usage in the documentation, and yeah it seems faster to iterate-and-mutate a mutable sequence with just two integers to control iteration. Still, I'm picking up Python for rapidly solving code problems, not so much performance. But I do wonder if the cost of invoking the `for i in` iterable, or calling a generator function (like `range`,  `enumerate`, `itertools.count`) would run a little slower than the `while` loop pattern in your answer.

Comment: @codeReview, depends on the implementation you are using. `while` loop is faster in pypy, but slower under cPython. In either case it's a micro optimisation and wouldn't be the first place i'll be looking to get better performance. pypy was ~30 times faster for a loop than cPython, so if you are writing code with lots of loops it's something to consider.

Comment: I've been using CPython 3.4.0 64-bit, as python.org makes it easily accessible for beginners. I couldn't resist trying out NumPy, but for now I'm just working on becoming fluent with the built-in modules of CPython before I move on to other flavors. I should probably take the [advice on optimization](http://docs.python.org/release/3.4.0/faq/programming.html#performance).

Answer (score 5):

The foreach-style loop is pretty common in most languages now as it's rare you need access to the index of the collection and more common you only need the object itself. Furthermore, elements which would require an iterator as their is no random access (e.g. set) can be iterated with the exact same syntax as a randomly accessible collection.

In python, the correct way of accessing the index while iterating should be:

```
for i, x in enumerate(iterable):
```

At this point, `i` is your index and `x` is the item at `iterable[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look at using the range() function.

```
for i in range(n):
    A[i] = value
```

The function can be used as either range(n), which returns a list of integers 0 - n, or as range(start, end) which will return integers from the start value to the end value.  For example:

```
range(1, 5)
```

will give you the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Answer (score 2):

First, python has several ways to perform *C style for loops* with the two most common being (the first you allude to in your post, ie. with the generator object returned by range):

```python
for i in range(some_end_value):
    print(i)
# or the many times preferred
for i, elem in enumerate(some_list):
    print("i is at {0} and the value is {1}".format(i, elem))
```

As to why python is setup this way, I think this has just become a more convenient and preferred way of setting up foreach-style loops - particuliarly as languages have moved away from the need to define arrays/list with their max index. For instance in [java](/questions/tagged/java) one can also do:

```java
for (int i: someArray) {
    system.out.println(i) // which would print the current item of an integer array
}
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) (`foreach (int i in someArray)`) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (`for (auto &i: int)`) also have their own foreach loops. While in [c](/questions/tagged/c), most people tend to write macros to get the functionality of a foreach loop.

It's just a convenient way to access *dynamic* arrays, lists, dicts, and other constructs. While [while](/questions/tagged/while) loops can be used for activities that must modify the iterator itself - or just a second variable could be created and modified mathematically using the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Python is a higher-level language than C and iterating over a high-level abstraction such as 'sequence' is more naturally and safely expressed with another one  - 'iterator'.  C doesn't really have such abstraction so it's hardly surprising it expresses most traversal with a low-level, 'hand-operated' index or pointer increment. That's an artifact of the low-level nature of C, though - it would be silly for a higher-level abstraction to use it as a primary building block for all looping constructs and most, not just Python, don't.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way to have C-style for loop in python is to use range. Not many are aware of an overloaded function of range(stop) which accepts start, stop and step arguments where step is optional. With this, you could almost do anything that you could with C-style for loops:

```
range(start, stop[, step])

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++)    
>>> range(1, 11)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for (i = 0; i < 30; i=i+5)
>>> range(0, 30, 5)
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
for (i = 0; i < 10; i=i+3)
>>> range(0, 10, 3)
[0, 3, 6, 9]
for (i = 0; i > -10; i--)
>>> range(0, -10, -1)
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of the C-loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) A[i] = value;
```

i.e., to set all items in an array to the same value if `A` is a `numpy` array:

```
A[:] = value
```

Or if `len(A) > n` then

```
A[:n] = value
```

If you want to create a Python list with `n` values:

```
A = [value] * n #NOTE: all items refer to the *same* object
```

You could also replace values in the existing list:

```
A[:n] = [value]*n #NOTE: it may grow if necessary
```

Or without creating a temporary list:

```
for i in range(n): A[i] = value
```

The pythonic way to enumerate all values with corresponding indices while using the values:

```
for index, item in enumerate(A):
    A[index] = item * item
```

The code could also be written using a list comprehension:

```
A = [item * item for item in A] #NOTE: the original list object may survive
```

Don't try to write C in Python.

Comment: I would attempt use of the numpy library, but if I'm working on say, a hackerrank.com problem, numpy is disallowed, and besides, I'm trying to learn the basics. +1 anyway. I have basically been using the for `i` in range` loop pattern since I'd guess it's less expensive than `enumerate`.

Comment: @codeReview: don't optimize prematurely. Use idiomatic code unless your profiler says otherwise.

Comment: thx for advice, now it takes less time to code a solution, and optimizing would sometimes be unnecessary anyway.